# External OAuth2 integration with own OAuth2 spring server

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth-2.0, external, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to integrate Facebook OAuth2 authentication with my own OAuth2 server. Just to be clear the scenario is the following:

- I have a OAuth2 Server that is responsible for authenticating our users. I implemented a custom AuthenticationProvider that checks for the credentials provided and builds a UserDetails object if successful.
- I also have a rest-api that is also a ResourceServer (runs in a different application). So users after being authenticated they can access our rest-api providing therefore the token.

The token information is shared using JDBC.

Everything works fine as expected, but now I want to add external authentication providers such as Facebook.

My question is: what's the best way to do this? What's the expected flow? From the top of my head I would imagine something like:

1. User authenticates with facebook
2. Facebook provides a token
3. User sends the token to our OAuth2 server
4. I check the token validity with facebook
5. I authenticate the user using the authentication provider
6. The server gets back to the user with a new token issued by my OAuth2 server which the user will use from now on to ask for resources

Is this right? If so, how can I send the facebook token to my OAuth2 server? Is there some kind of standard? Should I make up new parameters for that? For instance I will be needing some way to differentiate facebook authentications from user/password ones.

Am I suppose to use my own AuthenticationProvider to validate this facebook user? It seems strange then return a UserDetails object that doesn't have a password...

Also, how to register users and auto log them in? Do I have to expose an endpoint of my own or is there some OAuth2 magic for that as well?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has some very good documentation on this with the correct flow and how you should handle the process.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2

You are on the right track, and I think the facebook documentation should help clear up any questions you may be having.

Additional Information is here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2

Comment: Thanks for answering. My question is more on how do I make my OAuth2 server aware of a facebook login. The interaction with facebook in terms of client I understand how it works. For instance, our main web application is not using an OAuth2 server. We validate the token and we login the client. But now us having an OAuth2 server as well it must be different. My question is how is that made.

Comment: You get a token back from facebook, you can inspect the access token  and verifying that your app_id, is_valid, user_id, ect.. and  create that 'user' in your user's table. If you need to do anything with facebook then store that token in your database. Once you inspect the token and it is a valid user in your database, you will then generate a new token through your OAuth server and link it to your user. You will use this token you generate for your API calls, grab facebook from the db if you need to make any API calls to FB. Your token can then be used to determine the permissions of user.

Comment: OK. And the communication between the app/web/etc to my auth server is  a call to /oauth/token as well? If yes, what parameter should I use. That is my main concern right now. Is there some kind of standard call for that or should I just make one up and deal with it in the server? Also, my AuthenticationProvider is expecting some internal structure provided by the spring oauth2...

Comment: Yep, you will use a token (not facebooks). Recall you will create a new token and assign that to your users table after you inspected the facebook token and determined they are authenticated and are who they said they are. So this token should be used to lookup the current user provided on each REST API call and determine whether or not that particular user is authorized for the request.

Comment: Thanks for everything but you are still no answering the question... This is how I authenticate users right now curl -X POST -vu webapp:PASS http://localhost:8081/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=pass&username=user&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write". My question is what's the structure to provide the Facebook token? Do I have to make up my own and deal with it on the server? That's my question. I know how to do it, I'm just trying to understand the best or the supposed way of doing it. Thanks again!